The vector space dimension of Selmer group of abelian variety
Let $A/K$ be an abelian variety with $\mathbb{Z}[\mu_p] \subset End_K(A).$
Let $\pi$ be the prime of $p$, i.e. $(p)=(\pi^{p-1})$.
I want to obtain the relation of Selmer groups $Sel_\pi(A/K)$ and $Sel_p(A/K)$?
Using the Kummer theory, I obtained the exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \frac{A(K)[\pi^{p-2}]}{\pi (A(K)[p])} \rightarrow H^1(K,A[\pi]) \rightarrow H^1(K,A[p])[\pi] \rightarrow 0.$$
Can we say that $$\dim_p(Sel_\pi(A/K)) \le \dim_p(Sel_p(A/K)) + \dim_p \frac{A(K)[\pi^{p-2}]}{\pi (A(K)[p])}?$$
Or if not, can we obtain the relation of dimension of two Selmer groups?
